# Why is Makefile relinking?

Tags: makefile

I was trying to make a more complex Makefile with a src dir and a obj dir.
But doing that the Makefile is now relinking, and I don't understand why.

```
NAME =      program
SRC =       main.cpp
SRC_DIR =   src/
OBJ =       $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OBJ_DIR =   obj/
CC =        c++
CFLAGS =    -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98 -fsanitize=address

all:        $(NAME)

$(OBJ):     $(OBJ_DIR)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)$(SRC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ)

$(OBJ_DIR):
            mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)

$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

clean:
            rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)

fclean:     clean
            rm -f $(NAME)

re:         fclean all

.PHONY:     all clean fclean re
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question, along with what you did with it, what you saw and what you expected. Further, review the tags you applied, see in particular their descriptions. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `$(NAME)` depends on `$(OBJ)`, `$(OBJ)` depends on `$(OBJ_DIR)`, and `$(OBJ_DIR)` depends on nothing, so it has to be remade every time, so everything that depends on it has to be remade. Also `$(OBJ)` is a list of your object file(s), but it has no path, so they are supposed to be in your working directory, but the command to make them puts them in `obj`. So the `$(OBJ)` files do not exist and have to be made every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
OBJ =       $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
```

This becomes `main.o`

```
$(OBJ):     $(OBJ_DIR)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)$(SRC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ)
```

and this becomes:

```
main.o:     obj/
            c++ [options] -o obj/main.o
```

This will result in the compiler creating `obj/main.o`. `main.o` still does not exist. So, on the next `make` run, `make` will valiantly try to build it, with the same results (not to mention that an explicit dependency on a ***directory*** will create its own set of problems, too).

Comment: And also not to mention, your object files don't depend on any source files and so the entire point of a makefile (to rebuild an object when its source changes) is broken here.